# Fast factorial computation

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory, factorial

I'm trying to solve this problem - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/711/E

I've already found and proved that the result is equal to:
$$
    1 - \frac{2^n (2^n - 1) \cdots (2 ^ n - k + 1)}{2^{nk}}.
$$
Now I need to compute it, and it's hard as $n$ and $k$ could both be as large as $10^{18}$. Computing $2^{nk}$ is easy. But I have a problem with this factorial. Result, of course, only need to be found modulo $10^6 + 3$.

EDIT:

Note that A and B must be coprime **before** their remainders modulo $10^6 + 3$ are taken.

Comment: If $k \geq 10^6 + 3$ then the answer is simply $1$. Otherwise, compute $a=2^n \bmod 10^6+3$ as usual, and then multiply $a(a-1)\cdots(a-k+1)$, at most $10^6 + 2$ factors.

Comment: By the way, I don't see any factorial in this post.

Comment: This will probably help you: https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/factorial-modulo.html

Comment: @Dmitry Not really. If you try to compute $2^n!/(2^n-k)!$, you will just get $0/0$.

Comment: The numerator is just $0$ unless $k$ is smaller than the modulus, let's call it $m$. In the latter case, you can multiply the $k<m$ terms modulo $m$ directly.

Comment: @Yuval Actually, the algorithm computes a modified factorial with powers of the modulus removed, hence it will *not* be $0$. However, it seems to require a prime modulus.

Comment: @Yuval Thanks! I didn't get the idea that a small modulo could help me. So far I have only solved problems where modulo was only used to get a short result, and here it is an important part of the task. I'll try your method and see if it works.

Comment: @Yuval "I don't see any factorial in this post." By this factorial I meant a falling factorial which is also a kind of factorial.

Comment: I think tests for this task are wrong... https://pastebin.com/vVXitW3D

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, you can check the algorithm there, they ignore multipliers of the modulo. But I agree that your idea sounds much simpler, and it's clear how to implement it.

Comment: @yomol777, Let $m = 10^6 + 3$. After simplification the result has form $\frac {2^s - a} {2^s}$, where $2 \nmid a$. Note that, while for $k \ge m$, $m \vert a$, you can't simplify the original expression further. I.e. you should output $\frac {(2^s - a) \mod m} {2^s \mod m} = \frac {2^s \mod m} {2^s \mod m}$.

Comment: I missed very important thing: A and B must be coprime BEFORE their remainders modulo 10^6 + 3 are taken. So now I can't just print "1 1" for k > 10^6 + 3. I need to find another method. Here's my code that works for k <= 10^6 + 3 - https://pastebin.com/EGK2fCDn